# changing route variable for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just decided that the 'show' action of my 'users' controller should no longer render a page, but rather some json to be used by an ajax call.  **Edit: I've already implemented this part.  My controller just has**

```
def show
    render :json => myobject
end
```

My javascript in the views generate the url to do the AJAX, and all that works fine.  As for my question: I'm just looking to take a little shortcut; instead of going through all the places that I link to this action in a view, with something like

```
<%= link_to "Foobar" user_path(@user) %>
```

and replacing it with

```
<a href='javascript:blahblah'>Foobar</a>
```

I'd like it if `user_path` instead just spit out my javascript URI.  Admittedly, this sounds like a terrible hack, but can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hack, you can go to helpers/application_helper.rb and insert there

```
def user_path(*args)
  "javascript:..."
end
```

This will do the trick. But I don't recommend it as a long-term solution, only as a quick workaround to check how your new code works, probably.

Besides, if you want to build the link for the right user you'll need to parse all possible combinations of user_path parameters. If you only call it in the `user_path(@user)` format then it's relatively easy.

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well... take a look at my edited post.

Comment: Yeah, I agree -- you answered my question well, but I probably shouldn't actually use it.  I guess, with respect to my original question, this also shows how I could throw an exception to make my tests break where ever I use user_path (since it shouldn't really be used for what I want to do any more).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does putting this in the application_helper override what you normally get from the routes configuration?  Where do the definitions from routes even fit in at all?

Comment: this last subj deserves a separate big question. it's rather complicated how it makes it from ActiveDispatch to ActiveController, I'm definitely not ready to explain it well.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the format :

```
user_path( user, format: :json )
```

if you want your helper to throw an error, just override it in `application_helper.rb` :

```
def user_path( *args, options = {} )
  raise MyException
end
```

... or just use your favorite IDE / shell to find all occurences of the helper.

Comment: I don't think that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: i don't understand quite well your question, then.

Comment: I'm not looking to link to json instead of a regular format.  I've already changed my controller to return json only -- now I want to avoid tracking down every use of the variable and modifying it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a default format for a route in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :user, defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

If you only want to do this for `show`:

```
resources :user, only: [:show], defaults: { format: 'json' }
```